# producing some text file using a for loop in java?

Tags: java, file, text-files, filewriter

I am going to produce some text files(number of files is entered by user) using a for loop, but when the program runs only one file is produced because the file name doesn't change. I don't know how to change the names of file every time. my code is below which produces only one text file not as many as the user enters.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int p1 = sc.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < p1; i++) {
            try {
            FileWriter f = new FileWriter("textfile.txt");
            f.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: it is overwriting the previous file

Comment: I know but I don't know how to reform it in order to produce some text file in the loop. my goal is producing as many text files as p1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to give like this in `for` loop to create multiple file

```
 FileWriter f = new FileWriter("textfile_"+i+".txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a constant name for the file, use a String variable. If you want that the name of the file is unique each time you run your program, you can write something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); int p1 = sc.nextInt();

for (int i = 0; i < p1; i++) {
    try {
    String filename = "textfile_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".txt"
    FileWriter f = new FileWriter(filename);
    f.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

`System.currentTimeMillis()`  returns the number of miliseconds from 1.1.1970 UTC